# Product Reviews?

Tags: discussion

[Jefromi's answer here](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1159/959) suggests that Product Reviews might be a fun and attractive type of question we might cultivate, as a more manageable alternative to lists and polls. What should they look like? How do they work?

My first thought is that they should mostly be *Share Your Knowledge* type. That is, the question is posted simultaneously with an acceptable answer by the original author ([eg.](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9502/how-do-tape-wound-strings-compare-to-metal-flatwounds)). Otherwise I fear that in short order we'd risk overtaxing the tag system for organizing dozens or hundred of different *Mr. Coffee*'s.

Or can it just be anybody asking about some product they're considering? That doesn't sound right to me, based on my experience on SO and Music.SE. I'd rather see fewer more generalized questions like How to evaluate X-type of machine? or What to look for when comparing two brands of X type of thing?

Other thoughts? How can we handle product reviews?

Comment: [*Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!*](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and [*Why are “shopping list” questions bad?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/244929) should be read carefully before this kind of thing is discussed. RPG.SE [recently ended](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5711/4398) a several-year experiment in allowing game recommendation questions; citizens' reluctance to adhere to basic [Back It Up! principles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167259/how-widespread-is-the-back-it-up-principle) made too much work curating quality.